# Create custom permissions for user type

Tags: permissions

I'm currently wanting to have it so that writers on my site have to have an admin approve their content before it's published, but still be allowed to do other tasks such as uploading images, adding tags, etc, and the wordpress static permission levels are either too restrictive, or let writers publish themselves.

I know on drupal there is an easy way to edit permissions for account types, but I was wondering if there is a way to do the same level of functionality with wordpress at all.

Comment: Check out [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) or [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugins.

Comment: heres a brilliant resource for the info you required. [wp roles and capabilities](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/#add-capability)

Answer (score 4):

### Plugins that would do this are:

- [WPFront User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-user-role-editor/) -- free & paid both do what you're asking
- [User Role](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role/screenshots/)
- [User Role and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/)

### Or you can write it into your theme's functions.php

- consult [Roles & Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) in the WP Codex for the details
- and read this [easy-to-understand guide](http://www.wpmayor.com/roles-capabilities-wordpress/) on how to add those capabilities yourself

> *Personally, I prefer to write it into functions.php rather than install a plugin.  It's more secure and typically keeps your site running faster.*

Answer (score 3):

First, choose one wordpress role your writer'll have : author, contributor, editor... or a custom role.

then customize your chosen role with capacities in your functions.php theme file :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'writer_set_roles' ) ):
 function writer_set_roles()
 {
    global $wp_roles;

    // post / page editing
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','edit_others_pages');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','edit_published_pages');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','edit_private_pages');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','publish_pages');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','delete_pages');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','delete_others_pages');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','delete_others_posts');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','delete_published_pages');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','manage_categories');

    // appearance
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','edit_themes');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','edit_theme_options');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','manage_widgets');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','edit_widgets');

    // sample for plugin caps
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','NextGEN Gallery overview');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','NextGEN Use TinyMCE');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','NextGEN Upload images');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','NextGEN Manage gallery');
    $wp_roles->add_cap('author','NextGEN Manage others gallery');
  }
endif;

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'writer_set_roles' );
```

you should find all capacities in this file : 
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/schema.php

or in documentation.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities